# How to make an Android view that flips between views on swipe/fling

Tags: android, gesture

I'd like to make a view in my Android app that flips between multiple views on a swipe/fling.  I'd like it to behave more or less like the Android Launcher behaves when flipping between views.  In particular,

1. It should flip views on swipe.
2. Generally a swipe will flip between one view and the next. It should not fling across all of the views.
3. If you swipe slowly, you should see the views dragging as you're swiping, eg. the way the Launcher does it.

I tried using a ViewFlipper with a GestureOverlayView as per Romain Guy's [blog post here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html), but there's no indicator to the user as they're swiping.  This makes discoverability difficult, which is presumably why Launcher does it the way they do.

I tried using a Gallery object, but when I swipe from left to right, there's a certain amount of momentum that flings the users through all the views rather than just taking them to the next view.

Is there a good way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @google Seems like a great thing to add to the SDK!

Comment: You can find some recently updated official training on swiping views on the [developer site here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html). It explains swiping between tabs or any view for that matter.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I know this is an old question but ViewPager is created for this exact same purpose. ViewPager is part of android compatibility package and more can be found at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: Is ViewPager a replacement for ViewFlipper?

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at [HorizontalPager](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager). It's actually based on [RealViewSwitcher](http://marcreichelt.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html), which in turn is based on the Android homescreen's code, and supports snap-to paging with drag feedback, as well as nested vertically-scrolling subviews. Gesture support for fast swipes isn't all it should be, but this may get you part of the way there (and I'd welcome contributions back).

EDIT: As of 2012 you're much better off using Google's [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) - it's in the compat library.

Comment: Thanks Yoni, I owe you a beer

Comment: Best of all it's simple, with only one source file. It sub-classes from ViewGroup so you just add your pages as children in the XML. Set mTouchSlop = 0 for better swipe recognition.

Comment: @MelindaGreen I'd switch to ViewPager these days. I'm not maintaining HorizontalPager any more. While ViewPager is much more complex, it should cover all the same uses and then some; I'd only use HorizontalPager if you wanted to do something really custom that ViewPager doesn't support and you wanted a simpler base class to start from.

Comment: @Yoni, The added complexity is a big deal for me, so I'm more than willing to use a simple version with problems than to accept the maintenance cost of the 'correct' way. I've already made a bunch of changes to HorizontalPager and may well republish it along with other such utilities that I've written or adopted. Hint: call the user's callback from snapToScreen() rather than computeScroll() for snappier UI feedback.

Answer (score 6):

Check out SwipeView within this project https://github.com/fry15/uk.co.jasonfry.android.tools It does exactly what you want it to do and is super simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsGuy extended ViewFlipper to do it.
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-viewswiper
Ihaven't used this one yet so im not sure if it moves with your finger like the launcher if not your going to have to make an OnTochListener to do it for you in me.ACTION_MOVE you will update the view to change its position. I'll post some sample code when I get home if you don't get another answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but it looks like that's a fairly simple combination of ViewFlipper with GestureOverlay, which wouldn't give you the visual feedback I'm talking about as you drag (like the Launcher does).  I haven't tried the cwac-viewswiper yet so I may be wrong, but looking at the code I don't believe it does what I'm talking about.  Please let me know if I'm wrong, and thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: I noticed that after I answered. Sorry.

Comment: @emmby: Yes, `ViewSwiper` does not meet your needs.