# How to implement swipe pages

Tags: android, touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an Android view that flips between views on swipe/fling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071743/how-to-make-an-android-view-that-flips-between-views-on-swipe-fling)

I want to implement an application that has multi pages and swipe between them (like the market place).

I tried to use Gallery, but that does not offer a lot of options. Also I tried multi Activities with swipe Animation.

How to swipe between multi pages using touch with Android?

Comment: You need to add more context to your question. Please show us what you've already tried.

Comment: Use the ViewPager to implement multi page swipe, check this [tutorial](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537)

Comment: Best suggestion is to use the compatibility libraries and the ViewPager. [Android Developer Blog - Horizontal View Swiping with ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) That works for Android 1.6 and up - if you want to target Android 1.5 then you'll need to implement it yourself probably using the dispatchTouchEvent() method override in Activty, like this [example](http://independentlyemployed.co.uk/2011/01/11/intercepting-touch-events-for-swiping/)

Comment: You can find some recently updated official training on swiping views on the [developer site here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html). It explains swiping between tabs or any view for that matter.