# Android Sliding Transition

Tags: android, scroll, transition, scroller

I apologize if the question is of the newbie level but I just started learning android to create mobile magazine apps for my company and what I would like to achieve is an effect similar to the native iPhone's / iPad's scroller in the home page (one where the apps that are currently installed are displayed).

Page transitions will be made in accordance with the user's gestures. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

'Page transitions will be made in **accordance** with the user's gestures'

means not ViewFlipper's behavior.

I recommend to use ViewPager, which is available in android-support-v4 library.

search for android-support-v4 library and documents.

I'm open for any regarding questions.

Comment: I don't quite understand the instructions as mentioned here sir : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html    Can u please explain how to implement this? thnx!

Comment: See the examples in android library folder. path is C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\compatibility\v4\samples

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with ViewFlipper and gesture Detection.

View Flipper will help you flip between multiple views and gesture will help you to swipe between views to achieve it. Here are few links which will get you  started.

[How to make an Android view that flips between views on swipe/fling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071743/how-to-make-an-android-view-that-flips-between-views-on-swipe-fling)

http://www.mediafire.com/?fg32sn1345xn5dl

http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-viewflipper-and-slidingdrawer.html